# how to get javascript variable value in GATLING

Tags: scala, testing, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I have a response body and i need some spesific javascript value in that.(__processUniqueID)
How i can do ?

Gatling 2.3.1 version

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var __processUniqueID = '06c199ab-**********';
var __isDocument = false;
var __isDMSDifference = false;
var __hasSanction = false;
</script>
```

I want to output "06c199ab-**********".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression check:

```
.exec(
  http("Get Javascript")
    .post("my/endpoint")
    .check(status.is(200))
    .check(regex("""var __processUniqueId = \'(.*)\';""").find.saveAs("my_value"))
)
```

This will parse the response body and save the matching group in the session  under the key `my_value`.

See the documentation:

- https://gatling.io/docs/3.0/http/http_check/#http-response-body
- https://gatling.io/docs/3.0/http/http_check/#putting-it-all-together